# How to apply a drop shadow effect to QGraphicsItem?

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to QT and I want to draw shadow for my QGraphicsRectItem but it doesn't seem to be working
I use following code in my QGraphicsScene

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setBlurRadius(50);

QGraphicsRectItem * item = new QGraphicsRectItem(100,100,50,50);
item->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::cyan));
item->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
scene->addItem(item);
```

However, this works fine if I apply this to my graphicsView like this

```
 ui->graphicsView->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you create *effect* locally and this pointer is erased, so move declaration of *effect* to header file.